# QListview force fixed item width, option.rect is too big

Tags: qt5, qlistview

I want my `QListView` to not show a horizontal scollbar. All my items are of the same height so I set `setUniformItemSizes(true);` Now the list seems to check the width of the first item and resizes the following items to the maximum of the latter and the width of the `QListView`. How can I tell the `QListView` to give the items just its own width?

Actually I use my own QStyleItemDelegate and got a too large QRect from the `option.rect`. But the standard delegate shows the same behaviour, so I took out my delegate to reduce the amount of problem sources.

A short illustration of the problem:

First item's width is smaller than the ListView's width:
[image]

First item's width is larger than the ListView's width:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: Dont allow the space bar.

```
setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

This elides the text with the default delegate and reports proper option.rect in your custom delegate.